# How to share a feed on my page's timeline? Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-share

Long story short, I'd like to avoid users spamming their walls with my game's stuff, so I decided, when they click "Share" the feed to go on our FB Page timeline instead theirs.

At that moment I use

```
    public static void FeedShare(
      string toId = "",
      Uri link = null,
      string linkName = "",
      string linkCaption = "",
      string linkDescription = "",
      Uri picture = null,
      string mediaSource = "",
      FacebookDelegate<IShareResult> callback = null
 )
```

[FB.FeedShare](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.FeedShare)

to post on their walls and it works like a charm. Yet I think it could be better if it's on our page's timeline. Is this possible?

P.S. Our page I want to post to, isn't an app page.

Comment: every page/event/user/etc, basically everything on facebook has a unique ID. Copy that ID and past it in your toId field. You can get your page id quickly by going to your page via browser and copying the id after slash in url 'www.facebook.com/1234'. Alternatively you can go to your page's About section and scroll to the bottom to get an id. 14/Dec/2015

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, I did that but I got the popular Error Message: "Cannot post to a user who has not installed the application" so my guess is that I'd need to use some other method for that